# Vector Field, potential function

Tags: calculus

Verify whether the vector ﬁeld
$$
\textbf{F} = \bigg\langle z \cos(xz) + 1, z e^{yz} + 4y^3, y e^{yz} + x \cos(xz) + 1\bigg\rangle
$$
has a potential function. If a potential function exists, ﬁnd it.

Comment: Please give us your thoughts on the question so we can know exactly what you are struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector field that has scalar potential should be conservative. The curl of such field is zero:
$$\nabla\times\vec{F}=\left(\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial z},\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x},\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}\right)=0$$
The field $\vec{F}$ satisfies this condition.

If the potential function exists, the following applies:
$$\nabla\varphi=\left(\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x},\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial y},\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial z}\right)=-\vec{F}$$
So what you have to do is solve this system of differential equations:
$$\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}=-z\cdot\cos(xz)-1$$
$$\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial y}=-z\cdot\exp(yz)-4y^3$$
$$\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial z}=-y\cdot\exp(yz)-x\cos(xz)+1$$
The first equation gives us:
$$\varphi=-\sin(xz)-x+C(y,z)$$
where $C(y,z)$ is constant for $x$ but variable for $y$ and $z$, since we only integrated "partially". Now you put the result in the second equation and get:
$$\frac{\partial C(y,z)}{\partial y}=-z\cdot\exp(yz)-4y^3$$
$$C(y,z)=-\exp(yz)-12y^2+D(z)$$
So now you have
$$\varphi=-\sin(xz)-x-\exp(yz)-12y^2+D(z)$$
You put this result in the last equation and you get:
$$D'(z)=-1$$
$$D(z)=-z+\varphi_0$$
So the scalar potential you are looking for is
$$\varphi=\varphi_0-(\sin(xz)+x+\exp(yz)+12y^2+z)$$

Comment: wow much easier then I thought it was gonna be lol